# Oracle SQL: Return text in string based on search of string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, substring

The following is an example of the text I want to create a function to query against:

```
"!PRINTSERVER.PAR
$MODE=QUIET
$DEBUG=N
$LOG_FILE=[file path]
$PRINTER_LIST=
-ACCOUNTS_LASER,\\print02\Accounts_Laser,winspool,Ne34:
-BE_PRINTER01,\\print01\BE_Printer01,winspool,Ne03:
-CUSTSERV_PRINTER,\\print01\CS_Laser,winspool,Ne06:
```

As an 'in' parameter of my function I want to search for the logical printer name, e.g. `ACCOUNTS_LASER` and I would like it to return the physical path e.g. `\\print02\Accounts_Laser`.

Also, the field in question that contains the aforementioned text has a data type of `long`, therefore I believe it requires converting to a string before any Oracle functions can be applied to it.

I would guess that I need a combination of `substr` and `instr` or maybe `regexp` however any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who posted suggestions. I have used some of the sql in the answers below to create a function that solves my issue.

```
create or replace function get_printer_path (l_printer_name in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
  p_printer_path varchar2(5000);
  cursor temp is
  select 
    regexp_replace(dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select info from print_server where 
    server_name = ''STAGING'''), '.*-'|| l_printer_name ||',([^,]*),.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'n')
  from dual;
begin
  open temp;
  fetch temp into p_printer_path;

  if (p_printer_path not like '\\%') then
   p_printer_path := null;
  end if;

  close temp;
  return p_printer_path;
end get_printer_path;
```

Any further enhancements or if I am breaking any standard practices then please continue to comment.

Answer (score 3):

#### Regex

```
'^(.*?' || 'ACCOUNTS_LASER' || ',)([^,]+)(.*)$'
```

#### Flags

```
n
```

#### Description

```
^(.*?<Printer name goes here>',)([^,]+)(.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Recipe

```
-- INIT
create table test (input clob);

insert into test(input) values('
"!PRINTSERVER.PAR
$MODE=QUIET
$DEBUG=N
$LOG_FILE=[file path]
$PRINTER_LIST=
-ACCOUNTS_LASER,\\print02\Accounts_Laser,winspool,Ne34:
-BE_PRINTER01,\\print01\BE_Printer01,winspool,Ne03:
-CUSTSERV_PRINTER,\\print01\CS_Laser,winspool,Ne06:
');

-- SELECT
select
    regexp_replace(input, '^(.*?' || 'ACCOUNTS_LASER' || ',)([^,]+)(.*)$','\2', 1, 0, 'n') printer_path
from
    test

union all

select
    regexp_replace(input, '^(.*?' || 'BE_PRINTER01' || ',)([^,]+)(.*)$','\2', 1, 0, 'n') printer_path
from
    test

union all

select
    regexp_replace(input, '^(.*?' || 'CUSTSERV_PRINTER' || ',)([^,]+)(.*)$','\2', 1, 0, 'n') printer_path
from
    test
```

outputs

```
|PRINTER_PATH              |
|--------------------------|
| \\print02\Accounts_Laser |
| \\print01\BE_Printer01   |
| \\print01\CS_Laser       |
```

Comment: Just curious: How did you create the image illustrating the regex?

Answer (score 0):

I obviously don't know your real requirements, but assuming the data is stored in a table called test_tbl, something like this could get you on the right track:

```
DECLARE
    FUNCTION printer_path(printer_name_in IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
        v_retval VARCHAR2(1000);
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (select col from test_tbl)
        LOOP
            IF regexp_like(rec.col, '.*-'||printer_name_in||',([^,]*),.*', 'n')
            THEN
                v_retval := regexp_replace(rec.col, '.*-'||printer_name_in||',([^,]*),.*', '\1', 1, 1, 'n');
                EXIT; -- exit loop if data found (not sure what your real requirements are)
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN v_retval;
    END printer_path;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Path: '||printer_path('ACCOUNTS_LASER'));
END;
```

Breaking down the regexp_ functions:

- Match any character, followed by a "-", followed by the passed in name, followed by a comma, followed by anything that isn't a comma, followed by a comma, followed by any character
- The parenthesis in ([^,]*) grabs that information to be able to use in a backreference later
- the 'n' as the match parameter just lets "." match the new line character.

I hope this helps, but be sure to test a lot of scenarios as I have no idea what your data might actually look like!

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with two completely independent problems.  The first is this:

> the field in question that contains the aforementioned text has a data type of long

LONG is deprecated and Oracle recommends converting to CLOB if at all possible, and gives extensive documenation and support for scrubbing them from your database:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_long_lob.htm#ADLOB008

I'll assume that's not an option, because this is life, and it never is.  If you are guaranteed that your LONG column will be less than 32k characters, you can fetch it into a PL/SQL VARCHAR2 string of up to 32k, and extract your printer path with a regular expression

ETA: NOTE - Code below will get an error if your long is > 32k... L_ROW.STR is actually a hidden VARCHAR2(32676)

```
create table t_long (str long);

insert into t_long values (

'"!PRINTSERVER.PAR
$MODE=QUIET
$DEBUG=N
$LOG_FILE=[file path]
$PRINTER_LIST=
-ACCOUNTS_LASER,\\print02\Accounts_Laser,winspool,Ne34:
-BE_PRINTER01,\\print01\BE_Printer01,winspool,Ne03:
-CUSTSERV_PRINTER,\\print01\CS_Laser,winspool,Ne06:' 

 );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_PRINTER_PATH (P_PRINTER_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    L_RESULT VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FOR L_ROW IN  (SELECT STR FROM T_LONG) LOOP  
        L_RESULT:= REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(L_ROW.STR,'(^-'||P_PRINTER_NAME||',)([^,]*)',1,1,'m'),'-'||P_PRINTER_NAME||',');
        IF L_RESULT IS NOT NULL THEN 
            RETURN L_RESULT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
END;

WITH SAMPLE_NAMES AS( 
    SELECT 'ACCOUNTS_LASER' PRINTER_NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BE_PRINTER01' PRINTER_NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CUSTSERV_PRINTER' PRINTER_NAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DUMMY1' PRINTER_NAME FROM DUAL)
SELECT PRINTER_NAME, GET_PRINTER_PATH (PRINTER_NAME) PRINTER_PATH FROM SAMPLE_NAMES;


PRINTER_NAME     PRINTER_PATH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ACCOUNTS_LASER   \\print02\Accounts_Laser                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
BE_PRINTER01     \\print01\BE_Printer01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CUSTSERV_PRINTER \\print01\CS_Laser                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
DUMMY1
```

If you will have strings longer than 32k, you'll probably want to go with a 2-step process: (1) create a Global Temporary Table (GTT) that uses a CLOB and (2) write a function similar to above that first puts data into the GTT and then uses Regexp against the CLOB:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_PRINTER_PATH_CLOB (P_PRINTER_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO T_CLOB
    SELECT TO_LOB(STR) FROM T_LONG;
    FOR L_ROW IN (SELECT REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR,'(^-'||P_PRINTER_NAME||',)([^,]*)',1,1,'m'),'-'||P_PRINTER_NAME||',') PRINTER_PATH
                  FROM   T_CLOB)
    LOOP
        IF L_ROW.PRINTER_PATH IS NOT NULL THEN
            COMMIT;
            RETURN L_ROW.PRINTER_PATH;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;                      
    RETURN NULL;        
END;
```